# Pythonic handling of IF block with two possible values

Tags: python

If I have a function or method which accepts a parameter which can only be one of two values, is it more pythonic to explicitly state both known conditions or abstract one away in the else clause? For example:

Option 1:

```
def main(group_name):
    if group_name == 'request':
        do_something()
    else:
        do_something_else()
```

Or option 2:

```
def main(group_name):
    if group_name == 'request':
        do_something()
    elif group_name == 'response':
        do_something_else()
    else:
        raise Exception
```

Comment: Depending on the input, those two options present very different behaviors. Only the second addresses "can only be one of two values" if `group_name` is not constrained earlier.

Comment: If the value does not have significance and there are only two options use boolean values instead of string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Explicit is better than implicit. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/

More importantly, the second option is probably safer in many scenarios. If only two values X and Y are possible, then you shouldn't trust that it is Y if it isn't X and assume that with the else statement.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest `Option 2` since its always a good practice to keep as many `endpoints / conditions` as possible. For a given problem, always model functions to work properly even when for now we don't see any problem/ may remove one condition but that may not be a best way for other to understand in production. In real corporate world, we need to put many many `conditions` and `exceptions` despite simpler needs to use and get rid of any fault at code base and greatly rely on the reusable functions to get works done faster.

Answer (score 1):

Explicit is better than implicit per [PEP 20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

for example:

```
def myfunct(param):
    possible_values = [x,y]

    if param not in possible_values:
         raise ValueError

    elif param == x:
         do something

    elif param == y:
         do something else
```